Localstack SQS Missing Action
I'm using a fairly simple set up with local stack to emulate reading from an AWS SQS queue. When I run this boiler plate code I get an error about missing action.
Exception has occurred: CLR/Amazon.SQS.AmazonSQSException
An exception of type 'Amazon.SQS.AmazonSQSException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user code: 'MissingAction; see the SQS docs.'

I'm not really sure where to go from here. I've searched high and low for this error, but I haven't been able to find anything. This is my code.
using Amazon;
using Amazon.Extensions.NETCore.Setup;
using Amazon.SQS;
using Amazon.SQS.Model;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

var awsCredentials = new Amazon.Runtime.BasicAWSCredentials("key", "secret");
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddAWSService<IAmazonSQS>(new AWSOptions {
     DefaultClientConfig =
    {
        ServiceURL = "http://localhost:4576",
        UseHttp = true,
    },
    Credentials = awsCredentials,
    Region = RegionEndpoint.USEast1
});
var provider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

var sqsClient = provider.GetRequiredService<IAmazonSQS>(); 

 var response = await sqsClient.ReceiveMessageAsync(new ReceiveMessageRequest{
        QueueUrl="http://localhost:4576/000000000000/CustomerEventQueue",
        MaxNumberOfMessages=10,
        WaitTimeSeconds=2
        // (Could also request attributes, set visibility timeout, etc.)
      });

Console.ReadLine();


Hi,
LocalStack and SQS queues run as default on port 4566 and not 4576 as setup in your sample. Please see our docs here:
SQS Docs

In the config we changed it to run in 4576.

I can see in the local stack container this error is being logged exception during call chain: Operation detection failed. Missing Action in request for query-protocol service ServiceModel(sqs).

I just got exactly the same issue. Looks like you have incompatible version see github
Looks like that SQS did change their protocol to JSON, and they released new version of SDK, while localstack did not follow it.
So you have an option to update all to latest version or downgrade AWSSDK.Core to  3.7.200.67 or lower.
So far because of time constraints we downgraded our SDK due to some limitations with whitelisting of containers.

Perfect! That worked for me. I had no idea aws changed their protocol. Thank you!

@mituw16 did you end up bumping up all to latest version or downgrading?

Downgraded the aws sdk. Unfortunately upgrading localstack to the most recent version isn't an option for us at the moment.
